Index entries on the same page
I have the command
\index[subjectindex]{foo}%
on several places in the text. Two of them are on the same page, so I get in the index
foo, 7, 7, 11, 22
which I would like to avoid. I can do it manually, i.e., delete one of the 2 commands but that sounds like a bad solution. That is, if I add some text before page 7, the references may find themselves on different pages. Can LaTeX track this?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc,name=subjectindex,title={Subject Index}]
\begin{document} Here we introduce FOO.
\index[subjectindex]{foo|textbf}%
and then we mention it again.
\index[subjectindex]{foo}%
\printindex[subjectindex]
\end{document}

Are you using makeindex and what .ist file are you using? The 7, should have been compressed to one entry in any case.

I am using \usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc,name=subjectindex,title={Subject Index}]

I think that the problem is that I want the first occurrence of foo to be in boldface so I have  \index[subjectindex]{foo|textbf}% on one of the 2 places.

Without a MWE is hard to explain, but you probably better to use a main entry and subentries, say \index{Foo Gods! foo,main},  \index{Foo Gods!foo minor}.

Here is a mwe:   \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc,name=subjectindex,title={Subject Index}]
\begin{document}
Here we introduce FOO.
\index[subjectindex]{foo|textbf}
and then we mention it again.
\index[subjectindex]{foo}
\printindex[subjectindex]
\end{document}

Makeindex assumes the different styles denote different classes of entry, so suppresses the usual merging of page numbers. If you do not want that why are the entries differently styled?

@David Carlisle
My MWE focused on syntax. In reality, the first mention of foo is followed by its definition, the later are situations where the concept is used in theorems.

I think you need to not style them differently so the page numbers merge and then arrange that the first use is bold via the index style if that's what you need. for example if you use |myfirstbold| or some such command you could define that command to make the first use bold then do nothing, and reset it each index entry, or whatever your actual requirement is.

Is one of the page numbers set in bold?  That's where the distinction would come.  (I'm not sure of the proper way to accomplish that; I used to know, but have forgotten.)

@David Carlisle  Thank you for the ideas. Sadly, it won't help because the location I want in bold is not always the first one.

then makeindex really thinks you shouldn't merge the numbers (and I am inclined to agree with it) you can as you say force things by hand, and I can't think of anything else, sorry. (someone else may answer though)

Further to your explanation, I suggest you abandon the idea, as if you happen to have a definition and a theorem in the same page, you will not have the theorem indexed, if the entries are merged. Rather consider making both the entry and the page in bold for the defnition index entry, with a suitable explanation in the index prologue. Zeus Definition:\\ \index[subjectindex]{Zeus@\textbf{Zeus}|textbf} Zeus Theorem: \index[subjectindex]{Zeus} \printindex[subjectindex]  .
